# Sobolev Multiplication on non-compact manifold

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

We know that for a compact Riemannian $n$-dim  manifold  $(M,g)$(the boundary could be nonempty),  the Sobolev Multiplication Theorem states that $L^p_k\times L^q_l⟶L^r_m$, where $1/r−m/n>1/p−k/m+1/q−l/n$ and  $m\leq\min(l,k)$.

**Q** If $M$ is non-compact, does the Sobolev Multiplication Theorem still holds?

PS:

- If $k=l=m=0$, we know that it is true. 
  Could anyone give a reference for the case $k,l,m\geq1$?
- The problem is that can we have an embedding $$L^p_k\hookrightarrow L^{p*},$$
  where $\frac1{p^*}=\frac1p-\frac{k}{n}$ for the complete manifold(bounded geometry).